# jquery solo ejecuta la acción de un boton

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy desarrollando una interfaz que al recibir 3 valores los envia mediante un boton usando jquery a un php y carga su contenido en un contenedor, despues muestro otros 4 botones, que toman los 3 primeros valores y los envia a otro php y los carga en un contenedor, mi problema es que en los 4 ultimos botones, solo realiza la accion del que presiono primero que es mostrar el contenedor que le corresponde y cargarlo con el php, si presiono alguno otro ya no ejecuta la accion de enviar y cargar los datos del php en el contenedor, pero si lo muestra el contenedor que le corresponde

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#grafi').hide();
  $('#g1').hide();
  $('#g2').hide();
  $('#g3').hide();
  $('#g4').hide();

  $('#btn0').click(function() {
    $('#grafi').show();
    valor1 = $('#year1').val();
    valor2 = $('#year2').val();
    valor3 = $('#year3').val();

    $("#tabla").load('tablas.php', {
      valor1,
      valor2,
      valor3
    });
    return false;
  });





  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $('#g1').show();
    $('#g2').hide();
    $('#g3').hide();
    $('#g4').hide();
    valor1 = $('#year1').val();
    valor2 = $('#year2').val();
    valor3 = $('#year3').val();
    $("#g1").load('graficasComGLP.php', {
      valor1,
      valor2,
      valor3
    });

    return false;
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $('#g1').hide();
    $('#g2').show();
    $('#g3').hide();
    $('#g4').hide();
    valor1 = $('#year1').val();
    valor2 = $('#year2').val();
    valor3 = $('#year3').val();
    $("#g2").load('graficasComG.php', {
      valor1,
      valor2,
      valor3
    });
    return false;
  });

  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    $('#g1').hide();
    $('#g2').hide();
    $('#g3').show();
    $('#g4').hide();
    valor1 = $('#year1').val();
    valor2 = $('#year2').val();
    valor3 = $('#year3').val();
    $("#g3").load('graficasComD.php', {
      valor1,
      valor2,
      valor3
    });
    return false;

  });
  $("#btn4").click(function() {
    $('#g1').hide();
    $('#g2').hide();
    $('#g3').hide();
    $('#g4').show();
    valor1 = $('#year1').val();
    valor2 = $('#year2').val();
    valor3 = $('#year3').val();
    $("#g4").load('graficasComE.php', {
      valor1,
      valor2,
      valor3

    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn0" class="btn btn-primary">Mostrar</button>

<div align="center" id="grafi">
  <H2> Graficas de Comparacion</H2>
  <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary">Grafica Gas LP</button>
  <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary">Grafica Gasolina</button>
  <button id="btn3" class="btn btn-primary">Grafica Diesel</button>
  <button id="btn4" class="btn btn-primary">Grafica Electricidad</button>
</div>
<br>
<div align="center" id="g1">1</div>
<div align="center" id="g2">2</div>
<div align="center" id="g3">3</div>
<div align="center" id="g4">4</div>
```

Comment: Puse tu codigo en fragmento de codigo y funciona bien, seguro que tu codigo es igual que este? y lo que creo que te esta pasando es el shadowing creo que se llama, básicamente es que hay otro evento `$('#btn0').click()` en algún otro js dentro de tu aplicación.  Tu crees que llamas  a una funcion, pero en realidad estas llamando a otra oculta... ese es le concepto de shadowing.

Comment: si es el mismo, el probelma es que al precionar el boton 1, si manda los datos al php y se cargan en el contenedor, pero cuando preciono el boton 2, si oculta el contenedor 1 y muestra el contenedor 2, pero ya no envia los datos al php ni se carga en el contenedor

Comment: Yap entonces tal vez hay error en alguno de tus php, ya los probaste individuales?

Comment: ya, y todos funcionan por separado, la idea que tengo es que tal vez le hace falta una funcion o algo que recarge o reenvie los datos al php y este se carge en el contenedor, pero no se cual es

Comment: Tiene sentido, yo tampoco tengo idea, esperemos que alguien sepa la respuesta.